# Using a .NET Framework DLL with COM interop in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, interop

I have a .NET Framework 4.5.2 DLL which I want to use in a .NET Core 3.1 project. I know the classic framework DLL is not compatible with the Core framework so I can't reference the assembly directly. Porting to .NET Standard may be an option but a lot of work because it uses WCF.

I have two options:

- inter process communication
- COM interop

I read a lot about problems and solutions of framework/core compatibility, but nothing about COM interop.

What I did with Visual Studio 2019:
Framework dll: "Make assembly COM-Visible" + "Register for COM interop"
Core dll: add COM dependency

After I have added my COM dependency, Visual Studio displays a yellow triangle about the COM reference, no error. Does this means it should basically work but I did something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it will not work, it will throw you some errors on usage. Maybe my cases where a bit different, but I would be surprised if this will work. 
edit: from some other responses will not work. 
Could you maybe add a new .net standard project as a small wrapper over the .net framework DLL and then reference the .net standard project in your .net core app?

Comment: I tried your idea with a .net standard wrapper. Great idea but sadly the indirectly referenced classic framework dll is still forced to run under core: got a PlatformNotSupportedException after some lines of code...

Comment: ohh, ok. Last idea is to create a nuget package with that DLL targeting .net standard - and then use that package in .net core. If it's not too much hassle.